# Cant create table: "errno: 150" when not using H2

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, h2

Im developing a Spring Boot 3.1.2 template with a simple authority-role based authentication system, it works perfectly well in H2 but when i try to switch it to a MYSQL database i get the following error:

```
2023-09-06T08:10:47.750-05:00  WARN 5038 --- [main] o.m.jdbc.message.server.ErrorPacket      : Error: 1005-HY000: Can't create table `test_db`.`authority_users` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
2023-09-06T08:10:47.751-05:00  WARN 5038 --- [main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "
    alter table if exists `authority_users` 
       add constraint FK1p680qfwgk9kr8rsf18y90r09 
       foreign key (authorities_role) 
       references authority (role)" via JDBC [(conn=160) Can't create table `test_db`.`authority_users` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")]

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "
    alter table if exists `authority_users` 
       add constraint FK1p680qfwgk9kr8rsf18y90r09 
       foreign key (authorities_role) 
       references authority (role)" via JDBC [(conn=160) Can't create table `test_db`.`authority_users` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:92) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
...
```

**It is worth mentioning that this same implementation worked perfectly in Spring 2.x, so i dont get what is the deal here...**

Here are my related entities, im pretty sure this error appears the moment i define the `@ManyToMany` relationship between `Authority` and `User`.

```kotlin
@Entity
@Table(name = "`USER`")
class User(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    var id: Long? = null,

    var username: String? = null,

    var email: String? = null,

    var password: String? = null,

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    var authorities: MutableSet<Authority> = mutableSetOf(),
)
```

```kotlin
@Entity
class Authority (

    @Id
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    var role: Role,

    var description: String? = null,

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany
    var users: MutableSet<User>? = mutableSetOf(),

    @Column(nullable = false)
    var enabled: Boolean,

    ) {
    enum class Role {
        SUPER_ADMIN, ADMIN, MOD
    }
}
```

I tried switching the connector dependency using mariadb instead of the mysql one in the `build.gradle.kts` file (and in the `application.yml`, of course), but didnt worked...

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.1.2"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.2"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.8.22"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.8.22"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.8.22"
}

group = "com.sphirye"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")

    //DATABASE
    runtimeOnly("com.h2database:h2")
    runtimeOnly("com.mysql:mysql-connector-j")
    runtimeOnly("org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client")

    //JWT
    runtimeOnly("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson:0.11.5")
    implementation("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:0.11.5")
    implementation("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:0.11.5")

    // TEST
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude(group = "org.junit.vintage", module = "junit-vintage-engine")
    }

    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs += "-Xjsr305=strict"
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```